# Summarise the second column based on the count of values in 3rd column along with the name of the values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarise the second column based on the count of values in 3rd column along with the name of the values.

```
df:

Name Age year  
A 75 2000  
B 60 1990  
C 75 2000  
D 60 1990   
E 75 2030
```

The summarised output I need:

```
75 2000 2  
75 2030 1  
60 1990 2
```

I tried,

```
df %>% group_by(Age, year)   
   %>% summarise(n_distinct(year))
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```
df %>% group_by(Age, year) %>% summarize(n())
```

`n()` returns the count of each group.